# Drupal domain menu page not found

Tags: domain-access

I am using drupal domain module and I have 2 different primary links for 2 different domains. However even though the menu items are not displayed on domain B, if you actually type the menu like example.com/events the page is pulled in domain B.

I want to know if there is a way , if the menu thats used in domain A is pulled in domain B, it will throw page not found error(not even access denied error).

I am using the same database.

Any ideas?

Comment: As side note, I think Drupal would return an "access denied" page because the module implements node access permissions; it means the module says when the users have the right to access the page, which is the reason of getting the "access denied."

Comment: It does return access denied but I dont want it to return access_denied.I want it to send a 404 error